# What does SSMS show for a DateTimeOffset(7)?

Tags: datetime, ssms, datetimeoffset

It looks like such a simple thing, but neither of us know it for sure....

I have a `DateTimeOffset(7)` column defined in a table.

SSMS shows this value:

```
2014-09-11 08:00:00.0000000 +02:00
```

(we are currently in `GMT +2`)

Does this mean, it's 08.00 in OUR  timezone (so we can determine the GMT time by subtracting the +2 from the 08.00 (which then is 06.00) or is it 08.00 GMT and it's 10.00 (08.00 + 2) in OUR timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx):

> - hh is two digits that range from 00 to 14 and represent the number of
>     hours in the time zone offset.
> - mm is two digits, ranging from 00 to
>     59, that represent the number of additional minutes in the time zone
>     offset.
> - (plus) or – (minus) is the mandatory sign for a time zone offset. This indicates whether the time zone offset is added or subtracted
>     from the UTC time to obtain the local time. The valid range of time
>     zone offset is from -14:00 to +14:00.

So in your example, it's 08:00 in YOUR timezone (+02:00).